# Is it a good idea to use a relay for 433 MHz antenna TX/RX switching?

Tags: amplifier, rf, relay, switching, pin-diode

I am designing a PCB for a power amplifier for 433 MHz. The output power is 60 W and the power MOSFET I am using is an [RA60H4047M](http://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/content/product/highfrequency/siliconrf/module/ra60h3847m1.pdf) from Mitsubishi. The RA60H4047M driving is fine and I can get 60 W with 100 mW input. I am using an antenna at the end of the output of the RA60H4047M.

Now I want to receive a signal from the same antenna, so I want to switch between TX and RX with a relay. I will put the relay in both input and output. I was thinking of a relay from Axicom but they are only 50 W max. and the RA60H4047M produces 60 W output. Also, the UM1-12W relay seems to be obsolete. My questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to use a relay for 433 MHz UHF?
2. If so, what relay is suggested for safely carrying 100 W? I use them in an HF circuit.
3. Are PIN diodes an option? Are PIN diodes available that handle such power?

This is the sample schematic I am using:

[image]

Comment: Please link the **pdf** data sheet for the relay you are considering.

Comment: Re: 1. Whether or not your RF Relay is suitable for your frequency range is 100% subject to the datasheet of your relay. So, the same place you would be buying that relay from has other relays, and probably a sortable list of relays. I'm sure you'll find something. Re: 2. Product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here, sorry. Also 433 MHz is **not** HF. HF is defined to be 3 to 30 MHz. Re: 3. That's a pretty separate question! You might want to ask that as separate question.

Comment: (By the way, that's Bangladesh, right? There, the 430-440 MHz band is a licensed band, for fixed / below 435 MHz also for mobile services. Don't forget to properly terminate your transmitter while experimenting. You need a license to transmit on that band.)

Comment: @macus Muller I said I use tx/rx switch in hf. I want to do similar in UHF.I know what band HF is, as UHF is more higher frequency then HF i asked if it is ok to use similar switching. I am using UM1-12W-K relay. By the way that relay is obsolete.  https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/344323/FUJITSU/UM1-12W-K.html